# Increasing size of script area for Run Script in Xcode 8

Tags: xcode, xcode8

Not sure if anyone else has noticed this or if it is bothersome to others. With Xcode 8, I've noticed that the area for your Run Script has become very small. I've tried various things to try and increase height of the area, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. It's maddening because the area is so tiny.

I've added a screenshot to show what I mean.

[image]

I'm really hoping I'm doing something stupid as opposed to a newly introduced "feature" for an "improved" smaller script area.